# Newbie: Conceptual Understanding of W and U in RNNs

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

First Post, so please go easy on me :) Please post any comments regarding my questioning and forum skills, they will be gratefully received!

I'm trying to understand the matrix sizes and manipulations that make up an RNN. I'll go through what I understand already so hopefully we're all on the same page. (Alternatively you can TL;DR down to the question at the bottom)

X_Sets is a 2D array which has some sine wave values, Y_sets is a 1D array which holds the next sine wave value in the sequence for each record. the goal here is to accurately predict what the next value of the sine wave will be.

Initial Values:

```
learning_rate = 0.0001
nepoch = 25
T = 50  # sequence length
hidden_dim = 100
output_dim = 1
U = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (hidden_dim, T))
W = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
V = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (output_dim, hidden_dim))
```

Here's a snippet of the code I'm working with at the moment, its part of the forward propagation function. explanations in comments.

```
for i in range(Y_Sets.shape[0]):
   #select the first record from both data sets and print out the sizes for all to see
   x, y = X_Sets[i], Y_Sets[i]
   print(Y_Sets.shape) #(100, 1)
   print(X_Sets.shape) #(100, 50, 1)
   print(x.shape) #(50, 1)
   print(y.shape) #(1,)

   #clear the prev_s values as the computed hidden values will be different for each record.
   prev_s = np.zeros((hidden_dim, 1)) 

   #loop for one record.
   for t in range(T):
      #new input array is 0'd every loop
      new_input = np.zeros(x.shape)

      #we only fill the array in the t'th position, everything else is 0
      new_input[t] = x[t]

      #See Question
      mulu = np.dot(U, new_input)

      #Same issue here
      mulw = np.dot(W, prev_s) #why is W a 2D matrix?
      add = mulw + mulu
      s = sigmoid(add)
      mulv = np.dot(V, s)
      prev_s = s
```

Question:

I understand that there are 100 hidden layers and every hidden layer will have it's own U, so it makes sense to multiply each individual x[t] by a column of U. But - On the next loop round, t will be 2, x[2] will be in the 2nd column which will be dot-product(ed) by a different set of 100 Us.

Now - I was lead to believe that the whole point of RNNs is that they are efficient because U, V and W are constant over the entire sequence, whereas here we can see that they differ over the sequence.
Why?

Edit: Here's the Guide I'm following: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/01/fundamentals-deep-learning-recurrent-neural-networks-scratch-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaken. First of all, there is only one hidden layer with 100 nodes. Second, U is not changing after every time step, from the code snippet it looks like U is fixed and it will probably change after seeing the whole sequence. Same for V and W. I don't see the update equation here.

Comment: Hi PrayingMantis,

Thanks for helping out - could you tell me what you mean by only 1 hidden layer? In order to have more nodes, you need to have more hidden layers right?

Yes, U is fixed right now to random numbers, I wanted to understand the forward propagation first before the V, U and W values are adjusted by BPTT...

Comment: I noticed that hidden dim is 100 which probably confused you with layers. Typically neural networks have multiple layers and each layer has multiple nodes. In your case, it seems like there is one hidden layer (W, U and V are its parameters) and this layer has 100 units.

Comment: Yes, this is my issue here: I thought "Hidden Layers" and "Hidden Dimensions" were the same thing. Thank you for your answer!